# Django - links generated with {% url %} - how to make them secure?

Tags: django, https, url-routing

If I want to give an option for users to log in to a website using `https://` instead of `http://`, I'd best to give them an option to get there in my view or template.

I'd like to have the link "Use secure connection" on my login page - but then, how do I do it without hardcoding the URL?

I'd like to be able to just do:

```
{% url login_page %}
{% url login_page_https %}
```

and have them point to `http://example.com/login` and `https://example.com/login`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Curiously though, why would any user want to log in via a http when https is available?

Comment: Because their proxy only lets port 80 through (seen this aberration a few times)

Answer (score 19):

The `{% url %}` tag only generates the path portion of the URL, not the host portion. It only generates something like "/path/to/here" (all you need to do is "view source" and you'll see that's the entire contents of the `href`). It's your browser that assumes if you're currently on http://example.com the link should also be within http://example.com. So all you need to do to generate a secure link in your template is:

```
<a href="https://example.com{% url blah %}">
```

If you don't want to hardcode the domain name (and I wouldn't), you can use [the Site object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) and have it look something like:

```
<a href="https://{{ site.domain }}{% url blah %}">
```

Or if you don't want to use the sites framework, you can use `request.get_host`:

```
<a href="https://{{ request.get_host }}{% url blah %}">
```

Comment: This has 1 disadvantage though; when/if I move the site to diffrent domain, or something like that, relative URLs won't break, this one will. 
I was looking for something more like request.build_absolute_uri() function with option to replace http with https, but I guess it's better to implement it by myself.

Comment: Well, there is no way to force https and use a relative URL. Edited to mention that you can use the Sites framework to avoid hardcoding the domain name.

Comment: The above option using request.get_host is essentially doing the same thing as request.get_absolute_uri and forcing https.

Answer (score 6):

I've not worked much with secure urls, but I have worked a bit with satchmo, which has a middleware and some utils for it. The middleware just checks for the key `SSL = True` in the view parameters, and makes the request secure that way. You probably don't need to make it that complex, but you can take a look at how it's implemented.

Satchmo is on bitbucked [here](http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/wiki/Home)

I was also able to find a snippets for middlewares which also should be able to help you get a secure login url:

- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/
- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/240/

The first is the original, while the 2nd should be ab improved version, at some point, but might not be the case anymore. You can take a look into them.

Using either satchmo or one of the middleware snippets you should be able to do something like

```
{% url login_page %}
{% url login_page SSL=1 %}
```

Comment: The linked snippets are a good comprehensive solution if you want to define certain URLs as https-only and then have a middleware take care of it from there. They're overkill if all you are trying to do is create an https link.

Comment: True, for one link alone this is not worth it. In that case your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write a tag `url_https` that does the same thing as `url` but points to the HTTPS version of the url.